# How do you populate a parent value in a test class

Tags: unit-test

I have a custom object, "Opportunity Contact" that is a junction between Opportunity and Contact. In my LWC I'm creating records and it works alright. Now I'm building the test class and hit an issue. I'm trying to test different address value combinations on the Contact. I need to pass the MailingCity through to my class with Contact__r.MailingCity without DML slowing me down in the test. When I have this:

```
static void test_saveOC_noCountry()
{
    Contact c = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact];
    Opportunity oppy = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];

    Opportunity_Contact__c oc = new Opportunity_Contact__c();
        oc.Contact__c = c.Id;
        oc.Contact__r.MailingCity = 'Dan City';
        oc.Opportunity__c = oppy.Id;
        oc.Role__c = 'Billing Contact';

    List<Opportunity_Contact__c> oppyContactlist = new List<Opportunity_Contact__c>();
    oppyContactlist.add(oc);
    
    Test.startTest();
        String result = OppContactLWC.saveOc(oppyContactlist, oppy.Id);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

I get the error on this line:

```
oc.Contact__r.MailingCity = 'Dan City';
```

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

My question is how do you pass parent field values to helper classes in test without creating the whole record and then querying it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the reference to the object directly:

```
oc.Contact__r = c;
```

This puts a reference of c into the relationship field; you don't need to set MailingCity if you query it, or you can set it if you choose.